# question of neural network training：the gradient of the same module which is used multiple times in one iteration

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autograd

When training a neural network, if the same module is used multiple times in one iteration, does the gradient of the module need special processing during backpropagation?

for example:
[image: Deformable module]

One Deformable Compensation is used three times in this model, which means they share the same weights.

What will happen when I use `loss.backward()`?
Will `loss.backward()` work correctly？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nice thing about [autograd](/questions/tagged/autograd) and backward passes is that the underlying framework is not "algorithmic", but rather a mathematic one: it implements the [chain rule of derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). Therefore, there are no "algorithmic" considerations of "shared weights" or "weighting different layers", it's pure math. The backward pass provides the derivative of your loss function w.r.t the weights in a purely mathematical way.

Sharing weights can be done globally (e.g., when training [Saimese networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_neural_network)), on a "layer level" (as in your example), but also within a layer. When you think about it [Convolution layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/nn.html#convolution-layers) and [Reccurent layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.10.0/nn.html#recurrent-layers) are a fancy way of locally sharing weights.

Naturally, pytorch (as well as all other DL frameworks) can trivially handle these cases.
As long as your "deformable compensation" layer is correctly implemented -- pytorch will take care of the gradients for you, in a mathematically correct manner, thanks to the chain rule.